# Provide different access on content inside document in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, office-web-apps

E.g.

I have a document library having a document named "Employee Policy.docx" having information for employee of all departments.

Now what i want,

Is there any way to provide access of only HR related content inside document for HR department and same for others department?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: You may split the document into two parts or maintain two separate SharePoint pages rather than a document.